# Displaying a list over an image: the text goes to the right of it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an img element that I am using as the background of a navbar, I then will display the navigation links over the top of the img element. My problem as you will see in the images below is that the ul that holds the links get displayed to the right of the nav bar & not over it. Why does it do this & how can I get my links to be over the top of the img?

**This is how it looks now:** look at the white writting
[image: This is how it looks]

**This is how it should look**
[image: This is how it should look]

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/homepage.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Kamalei - Home Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
            html, body, div, form, fieldset, legend, label, img {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;  }  table {  border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0; }  th, td {  text-align: left;  }  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, th, td, caption { font-weight:normal; }  img { border: 0; } 

            body { text-align: center; min-width: 1200px; }

            #backgroundImg  { z-index: -1; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; }

            #heading        { height: 300px; }
            #main           { margin: 0 auto; }
            #navBar         { display: inline; height: 700px; width: 200px; z-index: 1; position: relative; } /* I am pretty sure the cause is because I use "inline" but I need it to position the navbar correctly to the left */
            #content        { display: inline; height: 700px; width: 800px; padding: 20px; padding-left: 30px; }

            #navBarImg      { position: relative; z-index: 0; padding-right: -5px; margin-right: -5px; } /* Remove gap between navbar & content divs */
            #contentImg     { }

            #navbar ul li   { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
            #navLinks       { color: white; top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; }
        -->
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="heading"> 
            abc
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <div id="navBar">
                <!-- Error occurs here: the unordered list is displayed to the right of the nav bar instead
                     of where it should be which is inside the navbar -->
                <ul>
                    <li id="navLinks">abcdef</li>
                </ul>

                <img id="navBarImg" src="images/navBackground.png" alt="" width="200px" height="700px"/>

            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <img id="contentImg" src="images/contentBackground.png" alt="" width="800px" height="700px"/>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Must keep the background image at the bottom of body -->
        <img id="backgroundImg" src="images/background.png" alt="" width="100%" height="1100px"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            window.onresize = setBackgroundImgWidth;
        -->
        </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make the navbar background a background image to the div rather than an image that's part of the html. This is the cleanest way to display the image underneath the text. You can set a height and width in the css to the div to ensure the entire image appears as well.

Comment: but what if I want the navbar background image resizable?

Comment: As i know it is not possible to resize background image,but it could be enough big to cover all of the element.

Comment: What do you mean by resizable? To contain variable amounts of content or to actually scale proportionally with changes in font size or if the page is zoomed? From the looks of your layout, if you're talking about the purple column to the left and semi-transparent one to the right, you'd be better off not using images at all but instead using border-radius and RGBa/HSLa for the background colours.

Comment: if the background image just needs to show a certain length, such as what you have in the screenshots, you can make that cut off through the height of the interior elements and padding. if you're wanting to round it off and mirror the top half, Tyssen's suggestion of using border-radius may work, but I'm not sure about the cross browser compliance...